# {discord.py-rewrite} Writing a leader board of user's names, and numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm sorry if the title doesn't make a lot of sense. So I have a discord bot that I want to have it so every time someone says "egg", it gives them one point. And if they don't say egg, it sets their points to half their previous points, with it rounding so it doesn't have decimals. I've tried to use the Pickle library to save to files, but it didn't look right, like it wasn't organized the same way I had it, it seemed to just save the minimum of what it could. Heres what my code currently looks like.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
TOKEN = 'token'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as: {bot.user.name}')
    print(f'With ID: {bot.user.id}')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong! Latency: {0}'.format(round(bot.latency, 1)))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    if message.channel.id == channel_id:
        if message.author == bot.user:
            return
        else:

            if ''.join(message.content.split()).lower() == "egg":
                return
            else:
                await message.channel.send(
                    "{} You fool. You absolute buffoon, it is illegal to say anything other than 'egg' in this server. I hope you feel the shame in side you. Us only saying 'egg' in this channel brings peace to our server, and you thinking your above everyone? above ME? You {}, have messed up. I want you to take a long time to reflect on your self.".format(message.author.mention, message.author.mention))
    else:
        return
    
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I'm aware this is very random. My end goal is to have a file of all the users that have said egg, and their current score. If you don't want to say how to give them the points, I might be able to figure it out. If you have any questions, I will try to answer them.

Comment: You can try libraries like `SQLite` or files like `yaml`, `json` or `txt`. I prefer `SQLite` or `json` for this program.

Comment: @Nurqm Thank you for your comment, I will look into SQLite and json.

Comment: @Nurqm I have experimented with json, and I can't seem to understand it, and I'm unable to understand SQLite, so I'm unaware of how to reach my end goal using these libraries. If your able, Will you be able to make an answer to this question Possibly explaining what I need to do, or how to do it?

Comment: You should use one of these. I can't teach you the whole library from the beginning.

Comment: I'd recommend SQLite and MySQL as well. They're extremely easy and efficient. MySQL database is what I'm currently using to store info on players. They work really well with RPG discord bots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.

The libraries I used were

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get
import itertools
import json
from json import loads
import os
```

The `json` file with the scores looked like this
https://hastebin.com/xicihepope.json
`{"<userID>": 46, "<userID>": 13, "<userID>": 35}`

The way I was able to get the score of an individual user was with this command
https://hastebin.com/eyoleduzar.py

```
@bot.command()
async def eggscore(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    os.chdir(r'Directory_Of_Json_File')
    user = user or ctx.author
    with open('EggData.json', 'r') as file:
        data = loads(file.read())
    score = data[user.mention]
    await ctx.send(score)
```

### HOW I MADE THE LEADERBOARD UPDATE

The way I was able to make the leaderboard update on every message that was "egg" with this code.
https://hastebin.com/utakorecuc.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    if message.channel.id == 783032255802245170:
        if message.author == bot.user:
            return
        else:

            if ''.join(message.content.split()).lower() == "egg":
                os.chdir(r'Directory_Of_Json_File')
                with open('EggData.json', 'r') as file:
                    data = loads(file.read())
                try:
                    author = message.author.mention
                    usernameList = data
                    authorsAmount = usernameList[author]
                    print(authorsAmount)
                    usernameList[author] += 1
                    print(usernameList[author])
                    print(usernameList)
                    with open('EggData.json', 'w') as outfile:
                        json.dump(usernameList, outfile)
                    return
                except:
                    author = message.author.mention
                    usernameList = data
                    addUsersID = {f"{author}" : 1}
                    whatToAdd = usernameList
                    whatToAdd.update(addUsersID)
                    with open('EggData.json', 'w') as outfile:
                        json.dump(whatToAdd, outfile)
                    return
            else:
                await message.channel.send("{} You fool. You absolute buffoon, it is illegal to say anything other than 'egg' in this channel. I hope you feel the shame in side you. Us only saying 'egg' in this channel brings peace to our server, and you thinking your above everyone? above ME? You {}, have messed up. I want you to take a long time to reflect your self.".format(message.author.mention, message.author.mention))
    else:
        return
```

### CODE FOR THE EXTREMELY UNEFFECIENT BUT WORKING SORTED LEADERBOARD

I am sure there are better ways to do this, but this is what I did.
https://hastebin.com/ikagajimev.py

```
@bot.command()
async def eggboard(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    os.chdir(r'Directory_Of_Json_File')
    user = user or ctx.author
    with open('EggData.json', 'r') as file:
        data = loads(file.read())
    boardData = data
    N = 3
    out = dict(itertools.islice(data.items(), N))
    SortedTop3 = sorted(out)
    print(SortedTop3) ## THIS IS A LIST ##
    print(out) ## THIS IS A DICTIONARY ##
    print(type(SortedTop3))
    print(type(out))
    FirstPlaceThing = SortedTop3[0]
    SecondPlaceThing = SortedTop3[1]
    ThirdPlaceThing = SortedTop3[2]
    FirstPlace = out[FirstPlaceThing]
    SecondPlace = out[SecondPlaceThing]
    ThirdPlace = out[ThirdPlaceThing]
    boardList = [SortedTop3[0],FirstPlace, SortedTop3[1],SecondPlace, SortedTop3[2], ThirdPlace]
    print(boardList)
    sorted_values = sorted(out.values())
    sorted_dict = {}

    for i in sorted_values:
        for k in out.keys():
            if out[k] == i:
                sorted_dict[k] = out[k]
                break
    sorted_dict_keys = []
    for key in sorted_dict.keys():
        sorted_dict_keys.append(key)
    sorted_dict_keys_1 = sorted_dict_keys[0]
    sorted_dict_keys_2 = sorted_dict_keys[1]
    sorted_dict_keys_3 = sorted_dict_keys[2]
    print(sorted_dict)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Egg Leaderboard")
    embed.add_field(name="First Place", value=f"{sorted_dict_keys[2]} has an egg score of {sorted_dict[sorted_dict_keys_3]}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Second Place", value=f"{sorted_dict_keys[1]} has an egg score {sorted_dict[sorted_dict_keys_2]}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Third Place", value=f"{sorted_dict_keys[0]} has an egg score of {sorted_dict[sorted_dict_keys_1]}", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

If you have any ideas on how to make this more efficient, please let me know,